# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function crearTitulos()

Tags: php, array, oracle, funciones, phpexcel

buenos días estoy tratando de crear una función con php que me rellene los campos de titulo automáticamente, pero cuando trato de pasarle el arreglo donde tengo mis titulos, me sale el siguiente error: "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function crearTitulos()", ¿Alguien tiene idea de como darle solución?

```
   $tituloHojaAlp = array('ID', 'línea', 'Modelo', 'Submodelo', 'Detalle1', 'Detalle2','Descripción','Compra Web', 'Formato', 'Moneda', 'Notas','Orden', 'Salto', 'Alcance', 'Amca', 'Hmx');

  function crearTitulos($objPHPExcel,$arrayTitulos){

     $columnasEx = array('A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1','I1','J1','K1','L1','M1','N1','O1','P1','Q1','R1','S1','T1','U1','V1','W1','X1','Y1','Z1'); 

     $long = count($arrayTitulos);
     $conColum = count($columnasEx);
     //ALP
     for ($i=0; $i <=$long ; $i++) { 
        if ($long == $conColum) {
           goto fuera;
        }else{
           $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)  
              ->setCellValue($columnasEx[$i], $arrayTitulos[$i]);
        }
     }
     fuera:
  }


  crearTitulos($objPHPExcel,$tituloHojaAlp);
```

Comment: Tu función, por lo que veo, no está cerrada, usando `}` y por lo tanto **no existe**. Identa correctamente tu código y verás el error en seguida. El orden es esencial en programación.

Comment: a mi el error me parece que esta en el goto, no sé si solo baste con poner fuera: o necesites poner una sentencia, por ejemplo fuera: echo 'algo'; inténtalo así, de cualqueir forma en lugar de goto puedes intentar con un break si no vas a realizar nada en ese goto.

Comment: @A.Cedano perdon si tengo el cierre, solo que aqui se me fue, ya lo edité.

Comment: @Sr1871 Ya intente con break y sigue dando el mismo error :(

Comment: `goto` !Dios mío, hacía casi 20 años que no escuchaba hablar de él! ¿Eso existe en PHP? Da igual... en vez del anciano `goto` puedes usar un `break;` si quieres salir del bucle.

Comment: He probado el código tal y como lo tienes ahora, y no da error. De todos modos, `goto` me ha causado un shock saber que aún se usa. :) Lo he cambiado por `break` y he quitado la etiqueta `fuera:` y también funciona. No sé por qué a ti te da error de función. ¿no será que llamas la función por otro nombre?

Comment: Comentario al margen, debiera ser `$i < $long`, puesto que los arrays comienzan en cero y vas a provocar un error undefined index.

Comment: @amenadiel, tienes razón ya lo resolví, me di cuenta haciendo un var_dump. Pero ahora me salta otro error, ¿Alguien a usado phpexcel?

Comment: @A.Cedano - Y en [PHP7](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.goto.php) sigue existiendo.. no olvides que PHP proviene del lenguaje `C`